# Video Summary generation using DL models [video summarization]

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I have asked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/78180330/video-summary-generation-using-dl-models) previously but no one asked so, here I am reposting the question.

I am trying to summarize videos based on some Deep-learning models. On doing research, the best I found is this [repo](https://github.com/sylvainma/Summarizer). I followed the documentation; Gathered the dataset, and trained some models. And also made some inferences. After some fixing, I could generate some summaries for the test videos given in the pipeline dataset. However, I want to generate video summaries on some custom videos that are not in the dataset. I am quite confused and stuck on this step for a while. Hey, Any help is really appreciated!